# How can I move both of my input text fields into the same row?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing my first website and I'm trying to do a tab where people can fill a form. I have two input fields for first and last name but they are on different lines.

[Photo of how the form is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivqAG.png)

I want to move both of them side by side to the line above, beside the grey box. Basically I want to have everything on the same line.
Below is the HTML and CSS:

```css
.Contact-Us h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#Start-registration {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 170px;
}

.First-name input[type='text'] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 35%;
}

.Last-name input[type='text'] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="Contact-Us">
  <h1> Contact Us </h1>
  <p class="Subtitle-Info"> Contact us via sending a message </p>
  <p id="Start-registration"> First and last name </p>
  <form action="" method="get" class="First-name">
    <label for='First_name'></label>
    <input id='First_name' name='First_name' type='text' placeholder="First Name" />
  </form>
  <form action="" method="get" class="Last-name">
    <label for='Last_name'></label>
    <input id='Last_name' name='Last_name' type='text' placeholder="Last Name" />
  </form>
</article>
```

Comment: Use flexbox or make the elements inline

Comment: I tried man. That was the first thing I did but it didn't work. That was also my first approach to it haha

Comment: `<p>` is a paragraph, so once it's closed, a new line is "inserted".  
Seems like the same goes for `form`.  
Why two forms?!?  
Also, you did not put text within the `label`s - do you really need them or could you add text?

Comment: Too much clutter and unused stuff.  Keep it simple...  Do you really need all that css?  ids?  Did you write all of that, or did you just copy a site and try to make it fit your need?  I did that at the beginning, and started throwing out stuff and now I (would like to think that I) code neat and simple and efficient.

Comment: `<form>`s are `display:block;` *(they break a line and have semantic values like height)*. You could do `form{ display:inline-block }` *(semantics with no line break)*, but I'm pretty sure you want all of your inputs on the same form. I personally don't even use forms anymore, due to mobile devices replacing the Enter button with the Tab button until you reach the end of the form, and the fact that you have to `formElement.onsubmit = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }` or the like when doing AJAX submission, which is always nowadays.

Comment: I wrote everything. I mean that;s the way I learned HTML and CSS. I started learning 3 weeks ago and I could say I'm pretty new. I'm sorry if it's a bit confusing but that's how I learned. And StackSlave, I tried what you told me and it didn't work. It made the input fields all cramped up

Comment: The inputs shrank because you have `.First-name input[type="text"]` and `.Last-name input[type="text"]` `width:35%;`. But really, use a single form.

Comment: Why are you using two different forms? Put the contents of both forms into a single one.

Comment: Because they are two input fields. One for First name and one for last name

Comment: @Aaron_Serpilin There is no need to keep each input field in separate forms. You can keep as many input fields as you like within the same form.

Answer (score 3):

You should have only 1 form like this..

```css
.Contact-Us h1 {
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   padding-top: 10px;
 }

 #Start-registration  {
   display: flex;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   background-color: #DCDCDC;
   margin-left: 30px;
   width: 170px;
 }

 .First-name input[type='text'] {
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 34px;
   width: 35%;
 }

 .Last-name input[type='text'] {
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 34px;
   width: 35%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang='en'>
        <head>
          <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
          <title>SerFin</title>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href='../test.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dropdown').hover(function(){
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(0);
                $(this).addClass('open');
            },
            function(){
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(0);
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            });
            });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <header>
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="../SerFin.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='Customer-service.html'>Customer Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="Info.html">About us</a><li>
                <li><a href='#'>Submission</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Search Engine <b class="caret"></b><a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Universities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Internships</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="setup">
                <li><a href='#'>Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
       </header>
       <article class="Contact-Us">
         <h1> Contact Us </h1>
         <p class="Subtitle-Info"> Contact us via sending a message </p>
         <p id="Start-registration"> First and last name </p>
         <form action="" method="get" class="First-name">
           <label for='First_name'></label>
           <input id='First_name' name='First_name' type='text' placeholder="First Name"/>
           <label for='Last_name'></label>
           <input id='Last_name' name='Last_name' type='text' placeholder="Last Name"/>
         </form>
       </article>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Mark this answer as accepted if you think this solves your question.

Comment: let me introduce to you a librarie that you will use really much.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. I'll check it out but your code didn't help, it stayed the same way. Either way, thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

Wrap both of them into one division like this:

```
<div class="main">
<form action="" method="get" class="First-name">
<label for='First_name'></label>
<input id='First_name' name='First_name' type='text' placeholder="First Name" />
</form>
<form action="" method="get" class="Last-name">
<label for='Last_name'></label>
<input id='Last_name' name='Last_name' type='text' placeholder="Last Name" />
</form>
</div>
```

Then style css:

```
.First-name input[type='text'] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
}

.Last-name input[type='text'] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main{
display:flex;
width:50%;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

This will do it.

I don't know why you created a form element for each input unless you are going to submit them to different php documents

Comment: Thanks man. But I copied it but the result was way off. The First Name input went to the left-the start- and the last name to the right-the end-. Either way thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```css
.Contact-Us h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#Start-registration {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 170px;
}

.First-name input[type='text'] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
}

.Last-name input[type='text'] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 34px;
  width:100%;
}

.the_edit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  width:100%;
}

form {
  width:35%;
}
```

```html
<article class="Contact-Us">
  <h1> Contact Us </h1>
  <p class="Subtitle-Info"> Contact us via sending a message </p>
  <div class="the_edit">
  <p id="Start-registration"> First&nbsp;and&nbsp;last&nbsp;name </p>
  <form action="" method="get" class="First-name">
    <label for='First_name'></label>
    <input id='First_name' name='First_name' type='text' placeholder="First Name" />
  </form>
  <form action="" method="get" class="Last-name">
    <label for='Last_name'></label>
    <input id='Last_name' name='Last_name' type='text' placeholder="Last Name" />
  </form>
  </div>
</article>
```

(You will see the desired results when you will expand the snippet)

You can play around with the styles further. The main thing to do is to wrap the contents you want in a single line inside a `div` and set its display to `flex`.

Comment: Thanks man. I had never used the fit-content width property. But now I have a problem, the inboxes arent as long as I wanted them, and when I change the width it breaks. Isn't there a way to make them in the same line but with the exact width I had put?

Comment: That's because each input field is inside a `form` tag. So when you set the input field's width to 35%, it is actually 35% of its parent form element. I am updating my code so that you can get the width you have specified.

Comment: Here it is! I have updated the code. Now you will see exactly what you wanted.